# change specific elemnt of ngFor where list is changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this `HTML` for show list of users :

```
      <div *ngFor="let item of users " [ngClass]="{'highlight': item.isDeleted }"
        class="d-flex selected-list-items mt-3">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-xl-5">
            <label>{{item.displayName}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-xl-5">
            <label> {{ getEnumTranslate(item.title)}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-content-center col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-xl-2">
            <button (click)="deleteUser(item.userId)" mat-button>
                <mat-icon aria-label="Delete" color="accent">delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and i create a validation with `private transport: BehavorSubject,` for do this :

when the transport is changes must be execute this code :

```
this.transport.listValue$.subscribe(data => {
        if (data != null) {
            data.forEach(element => {
                let user = this.users.find(x => x.userId = element);
                if (user != null) {
                    user.isDeleted = true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

and in html change the background color of find user in this code `let user = this.users.find(x => x.userId = element);` .

**now my problem is here :**

when `transport` is change it run code for change background and find that user but it just change background of first element in this HTML code ,
 specific user in the Third element but it change first element In the event that need change Third element in HTML .

**how can i solve this problem ?**

Comment: Please use https://stackblitz.com/ to create a demo reproducing your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the code that should work for your scenario. Here I am mutating the actual data inside users array. Please check and let me know if it resolves your issue.

```js
this.transport.listValue$.subscribe(data => {
  if(data != null) {
    for (const user of this.users) {
      if(data.includes(user.userId)) {
        user.isDeleted = true
      }
    }
  }
});
```